# Vaadin - PopupDateField not accepting multiple input date formats

Tags: date, datetime, vaadin, vaadin7, datefield

In my project I have a standard [DateField](https://vaadin.com/api/7.6.4/com/vaadin/ui/DateField.html) format as "dd MMM yyyy". I used setDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy") to se this format. But now users want to enter "MM/dd/yyyy", "MM-dd-yyyy" and "MM dd yyyy" formats too, with the displayable date MUST still be "dd MMM yyyy".

Right now when I enter "31/01/2016" in the DateField with [setDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy")](https://vaadin.com/api/7.6.4/com/vaadin/ui/DateField.html#setDateFormat%28java.lang.String%29) I am getting "date format not recognized" error.

My question is how can I make a datefield accept multiple date format inputs(not using the calendar picker).

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks for reading the post!!!

Answer (score 3):

You can override a method `handleUnparsableDateString`:

```
public class MyDateField extends DateField {

    @Override
    protected Date handleUnparsableDateString(String dateString) throws Converter.ConversionException {
        return super.handleUnparsableDateString(dateString);
    }
}
```

That method is called when `DateField` is not able to parse the input. You can parse the input in the method and return a correct `Date` instance.

Comment: Thanks Henri!! But I am using PopupDateField which is put in place using Vaadin designer so I do not know how to override the initialization of PopupDateField which is done by Vaadin Designer Generated Java file.

I tried to reassign the Overrided version on DateField but it is of no use.